# Connect Mikrobus OLED display with iMX 7 Board

Tags: embedded-linux

I have a i.MX7S board (WARP7) which has extension (Mikrobus standard) and an OLED C Click display (Mikrobus standard).
I try many ways but still failed to enable & display something on OLED screen.
Here are steps that I did:

1. Plug them together (with Mikrobus standard)
2. Bitbake and install "core-image-base" image (source code https://github.com/Freescale/fsl-community-bsp-platform -b krogoth)
3. Update linux kernel config with Staging/FBTFT module enabled all device (kernel source: https://github.com/WaRP7/linux-fslc)
4. Modify fbtft_device.c to add definition for my device

   ```
   .name = "oledc",
   .spi = &(struct spi_board_info) {
       .modalias = "fb_ssd1351",
       .max_speed_hz = 20000000,
       .mode = SPI_MODE_0,
       .platform_data = &(struct fbtft_platform_data) {
           .display = {
               .buswidth = 8,
               .width = 96,
               .height = 96,
           },
           .bgr = true,
           .gpios = (const struct fbtft_gpio []) {
               { "reset", 198 },
               { "dc", 200 },
               { "led", 199 },
           },
           .gamma = "0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 " \
                    "2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 " \
                    "2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 " \
                    "2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 " \
                    "3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 " \
                    "3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 " \
                    "3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 " \
                   "4 4 4 4 4 4 4"
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. Update Device Tree (imx7s-warp.dts) to add SPI support

   ```
   &ecspi2 {
       fsl,spi-num-chipselects = <1>;
       cs-gpios = <&gpio4 23 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
       pinctrl-names = "default";
       pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_ecspi2>;
       status = "okay";        

       spidev@0 {
           compatible = "spidev";
           reg = <0>;
           spi-max-frequency = <20000000>;
           spi-cs-high;
       };
   };

   &iomuxc {
       pinctrl-names = "default";
       imx7s-warp {
           pinctrl_ecspi2: ecspi2grp {
               fsl,pins = <
                   MX7D_PAD_ECSPI2_MISO__GPIO4_IO22    0x00000014 /* MISO */
                   MX7D_PAD_ECSPI2_MOSI__GPIO4_IO21    0x00000014 /* MOSI */
                   MX7D_PAD_ECSPI2_SCLK__GPIO4_IO20    0x00000014 /* SCLK */
                   MX7D_PAD_ECSPI2_SS0__GPIO4_IO23     0x00000014 /* CS1 */
               >;
           };
       };
       imx7d-sdb {
           pinctrl_brcm_reg: brcmgrp {
               fsl,pins = <
                   MX7D_PAD_SD2_WP__GPIO5_IO10 0x14 /* WL_REG_ON */
               >;
           };

           pinctrl_gpio: gpiogrp {
               fsl,pins = <
                   /*MX7D_PAD_ENET1_RGMII_RD1__GPIO7_IO1   0x14*/
                   MX7D_PAD_ENET1_RGMII_RD0__GPIO7_IO0 0x00000005 /* RST */
                   MX7D_PAD_ENET1_RGMII_RD1__GPIO7_IO1 0x00000005 /* INT */
                   MX7D_PAD_ENET1_RGMII_RD2__GPIO7_IO2 0x00000005 /* PWM2 */
               >;
           };
   ```
6. Rebuild zImage, imx7s-warp.dtb,  imx7s-warp.dts & copy to Boot partition (ums 0 mmc 0 mode)
7. Rebuild & install all modules  (ums 0 mmc 0 mode)
8. Reboot board
9. login and run command

   > modprobe fbtft
   >
   > modprobe fb_ssd1351
   >
   > modprobe fbtft_device name=oledc debug=3 busnum=1
   >
   > modprobe dmesg -c
   >
   > cp /dev/urandom > /dev/fb0

**===> In result: my display still black :( but only power led of display is ON** 
Output of command

```
root@imx7s-warp:~# modprobe fbtft_device name=oledc debug=3 busnum=1
fbtft_device: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
fbtft_device: SPI devices registered:
fbtft_device: spidev spi1.0 20000kHz 8 bits mode=0x04
fbtft_device: 'fb' Platform devices registered:
fbtft_device: Deleting spi1.0
fb_ssd1351 spi1.0: fbtft_gamma_parse_str() str=
fb_ssd1351 spi1.0: 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
fb_ssd1351 spi1.0: fbtft_request_gpios: 'reset' = GPIO198
fb_ssd1351 spi1.0: fbtft_request_gpios: 'dc' = GPIO200
fb_ssd1351 spi1.0: fbtft_request_gpios: 'led' = GPIO199
fb_ssd1351 spi1.0: fbtft_verify_gpios()
fb_ssd1351 spi1.0: init_display()
fb_ssd1351 spi1.0: fbtft_reset()
fb_ssd1351 spi1.0: set_var()
fb_ssd1351 spi1.0: Display update: 978 kB/s (18.394 ms), fps=0 (0.000 ms)
fb_ssd1351 spi1.0: set_gamma()
Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 12x12
graphics fb0: fb_ssd1351 frame buffer, 96x96, 18 KiB video memory, 4 KiB DMA buffer memory, fps=20, spi1.0 at 20 MHz
fbtft_device: GPIOS used by 'oledc':
fbtft_device: 'reset' = GPIO198
fbtft_device: 'dc' = GPIO200
fbtft_device: 'led' = GPIO199
fbtft_device: SPI devices registered:
fbtft_device: fb_ssd1351 spi1.0 20000kHz 8 bits mode=0x00
```

I suppose my display will enable and display something after these step, but it do not.

Did I make something wrong ?
Since I've never worked on embedded & Linux before, then i'm losing my way here.
It will be thankful very much with any help or direction

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: Did you enable debug of `fbtft` driver? Enable and dive into it, it might shed a light. I did connect two displays to Intel Edison module (via SPI) and had no problems with them.

Comment: I tried "modprobe fbtft_device name=oledc debug=3 busnum=1" but no error showing up. this is debug mode, isn't it ? Sorry I do not work with Linux Embedded before -.-